# unable to start IntentService

Tags: android, service, crash

I am getting the NPE while starting the service. I have just gone through the service tutorial on android developer site.

Logs are showing unable to resume activity...

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    CustomIntentService cis = new CustomIntentService();
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, CustomIntentService.class);
    intent1.putExtra("NUM", 1);
    cis.startService(intent1);
}
```

My service is :

```
public class CustomIntentService extends IntentService {
    private final static String TAG = "CustomIntentService";

    public CustomIntentService() {
        super("CustomIntentService");
        Log.d(TAG,"out CustomIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onHandleIntent");
        Log.d(TAG, "service num = " + intent.getIntExtra("NUM", 0));
        if (Looper.getMainLooper() == Looper.myLooper()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "In main ui thread");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "In worker thread");
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code for onResume to the following:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //CustomIntentService cis = new CustomIntentService();
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, CustomIntentService.class);
    intent1.putExtra("NUM", 1);
    startService(intent1);
}
```

This should fix the issue, remember intent knows which service to start and startService() is called on context. So here activity's instance will be the context.

Also,

Since Service is a component, so you should be declaring it in the AndroidManifestFile

```
<service 
    android:name=".CustomIntentService">
</service>
```

*Note: CustomIntentService should be under current directory, or you can supply absolute path also.

You can refer [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-fundamentals-intentservice-basics/)